# MySQL: How to select rows which have the lowest value in a field?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have following table and I like to get a list with all rows that have the lowest pointer. How can I realise this?

[image]

And this is what I like to get:

[image]

The problem is it should be dynamicly! So it's not usefull for me with "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE POINTER = 1".
At another time the lowest pointer could be 2 or 3 and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have subquery which determines the lowest value in a column.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE Pointer = (SELECT MIN(Pointer) FROM tableName)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that you can do subqueries!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table
where pointer = (select min(pointer) from your_table)
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer! I didn't know that you can do subqueries. 
今 草 顿 웃 was faster... Sorry